# TTS с помощью Яндекс.Станции через API

Tags: яндекс-станция

Каким HTTP-запросом, если это возможно, я могу заставить мою умную колонку от Яндекса произнести определённый текст?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/beldmian/yastation

Посмотри API там, по идее используется логин и пароль и дальнейшее вытаскивание из куки.

Comment: Насколько я понял, beldmian в своём коде не отправляет запрос, а предлагает создать сценарий с действием "Выполнить команду" "Скажи {любой текст}". Хотелось бы делать это менее костыльным способом и не засоряя список пользовательских сценариев. :)